# linq query with MyModel

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object model and I'm looking to populate it with a linq query.

```
MyModel{
DateTime AppointDate {get; set;}
int TotalAppoints {get; set;}
int AppointDuration {get; set;}
}
```

The query I'm writing is returning the count of appointments for a specific date and is in a function that receives the UserID and the date as parameters. MyDC is the data context.

So far, this is what I have:

```
var Output = from a in MyDC.AppointTable
             where a.UserID == TheUserID
             where a.Date == TheDate.Date
             select new MyModel
             {
                AppointDate = ?,

                TotalAppoints =?,

                AppointDuration = ?
             };
```

For now, I've tried a few things but it's not returning what's expected. When I write a.Count() I'm not getting the count. Each appointment has an int that stores the number of minutes for that appointment; TotalAppoints is supposed to be the count of appointments and AppointDuration is supposed to hold the count of all the minutes spent in appointments. Thanks for your input.

Comment: you didn't show your data model so how can someone write a linq query against it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is group your data by that field and sum across the values

```
var out = from a in MyDC.AppointTable
            where a.UserID == TheUserID
            where a.Date == TheDate.Date
            group a by a.Date into g
            select new MyModel {
               AppointDate = TheDate.Date,
               TotalAppoints = g.Count(),
               AppointDuration = g.sum( x => x.AppointDuration )
            };
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm getting Empty = "Enumeration yielded no results" and I know from the sample data that it should return values.

Comment: That meas that your (from a in Context.Table Where ... ) doesn't match anything and so you have no data to operate on

Comment: @frenchie - Perhaps you could provide sample data?

Comment: Ok, there was a problem with a where clause.